# How to copy a directory with symbolic links and resolve them?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, copy, symlink

I would like to recursively copy the *contents* of a directory which contains symbolic links (symlinks) as well as normal files with a Bash / Shell Script. I don’t know how to copy the symlink-contents. The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
for file in directory do
  if is symlink
    resolve symlink and copy its contents
  else 
    copy the file / folder
```

My directory-structure looks like this:

```
base/
  dir1/
  symlinkdir1*/ (--> ../somewhere/else/dirA)
    /file1
    /file2
  symlinkdir2*/ (--> ../somewhere/else/dirB)
    /file3
    /file4
  …
```

After the copy-procedure, I would like to have a directory-structure like this:

```
base/
  dir1/
  symlinkdir1/ (no symlink, actual directory)
    /file1
    /file2
  symlinkdir2/ (no symlink, actual directory)
    /file3
    /file4
  …
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`cp -rL /source /destination`

r = recursive
L = follow and expand symlinks

Comment: Needs a capital -R on MacOS

Comment: what's the difference between using L and not using L? The two other answers don't use it and I'm wondering what's the difference

Comment: -L will replace the symlinks with the real file. That's why my answer is the correct one and the other are wrong.

Answer (score -5):

Just use `cp` command with `-r` option to recursively copy. No need of a script all together,