# How do I copy a directory recursively and expand/resolve any symbolic links (symlinks) it contains in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift5, symlink

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511665/4991606) shows how to copy a directory recursively and expand all the symlinks from the command line ***using bash***. I cannot find the same functionality in Swift. Does such a function exist? How do I do this concisely in Swift? I could call this bash command from Swift, but would prefer a pure Swift solution.

[`FileManager.copyItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem) copies the symbolic links without resolving them.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901520/4991606) shows how to resolve a single symlink. However, I would prefer not to traverse the directory manually, checking if each item is symlink that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Use this [FileManager function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/2765464-enumerator) to enumerate a directory structure and then copy the relevant URL’s.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you need to write file manager code that traverses the directory structure manually.